# Eloquent, PostgreSQL JSONB and nested arrays

Tags: arrays, json, eloquent, laravel-6

I am in trouble with search nested JSON array in Laravel 6 app with PostgreSQL as DB.

Migration:

```php
$table->bigIncrement('id');
$table->string('comment')->nullable();
$table->jsonb('result')->nullable()
```

Model:

```php
protected $casts = [
    'result' => 'json'
];
```

JSON example:

```
{
  "suggestions": [
    {
      "value": "short value",
      "unrestricted_value": "full lenght value",
      "data": {
        "postal_code": "",
        "country": "",
        "country_iso_code": "RU",
        ...
        other fields
        ...
        "qc": null
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

I need to query JSON by country_iso_code.

Commands I've tried:

```
>>> Model::where('result->suggestions->0->data->country_iso_code', 'RU')->first()
=> null
>>> Model::where('result->suggestions->data->country_iso_code', 'RU')->first()
=> null
>>> Model::where('result->suggestions.data->country_iso_code', 'RU')->first()
=> null
>>> Model::where('result->suggestions->data->country_iso_code', 'RU')->first()
=> null
>>> Model::whereJsonContains('result->suggestions', ['data->country_iso_code' => 'RU'])->first()
=> null
>>> Model::whereJsonContains('result', ['suggestions' => ['data->country_iso_code' => 'RU']])->first()
=> null
```

I need help, I'm stuck. Thank you in advance.

NB: I can not modify database table and the way the data stored in because the data is shared with other applications.

PS: Sorry for bad English, it's not my native language

Answer (score 0):

I should use array mode for search

```php
Model::whereJsonContains('result', ['suggestions' => [0 => ['data' => ['country_iso_code' => 'RU']]]])->first()
```

returns expected data